# Show that I is directed via >=

Tags: general-topology

I have really a problem with understanding how I can show the following:

Consider a bounded function $f : [a,b] \to\mathbb R$ s.t. $a < b$.
A partition $Z$ of $[a,b]$  with the length  $n = |Z|$  is a finite set of points  $a = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n = b$ between $a$ and $b$. The set of all partitions of  $[a,b]$  with length n will be denoted by   $\zeta_n([a,b])$.

Moreover, we set $\zeta([a,b]) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}  \zeta_n([a,b])$. Now we consider the following set  $I=\big\{(Z,\xi)|Z\in\zeta([a,b])\}\text{ and }\xi= (\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\text{ with }\xi_i \in[t_{i−1},t_i]\;\forall i = 1,...,n = |Z|\big\}$,
which will be ordered by $(Z,\xi) \geq (Z',\xi')$ if $Z′ \subseteq Z$.

(a) Show that I is directed via $\geq$.

Could maybe someone give me a hint how to do that ?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please give the definition of "directed"?

Comment: I think it is to show that (I, ≥) is a directed set

Comment: transitivity is obvious, as is reflexivity. The majorant property is also quite easy: a common upper bound for two partitions needs all of the intermediate points of these two partitions, how to do that?